# Retrieving multiple tags per article into one Bootstrap table column

Tags: php, mysql, database, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I have a sortable Bootstrap table with a foreach (that I'm rather proud of) that populates the table from my articles db table.

At the moment, my articles table has 5 additional columns that represent tags, each individually populated.

The foreach works exactly as required (there is JS below this for the sorting but have excluded from here).

```
    <div class="MTable">
    <?php
    include 'conn.php';
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE Column_1 ='Value' OR Column_2 ='Value'");
    $table_a = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    ?>

   <table id="table_1" class="table display table-sortable table-hover table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Column 1</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Column 2</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Column 3</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Column 4</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Column 5</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Column 6</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(6)">Column 7</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
       
  <tbody>      
     <?php foreach($table_a as $return) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $return['Column_1']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $return['Column_2']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $return['Tag_1']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $return['Tag_2']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $return['Tag_3']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $return['Tag_4']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $return['Tag_5']; ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

I've have started to build out a tagging system and plan to remove those additional 5 columns from the articles table.

Did some research and looked through previous questions on stack overflow and have built out a three table system ("toxi" solution).

My table layout as per below with italics representing foreign keys;

- Table_a (Articles) article_id, more columns
- Table_b (Tags) tag_id, tag_name
- Table_c (Articles_Tags) id, *article_id*, *tag_id*

**The goal:**

I would like to consolidate Columns 3-7 into one Column and return all tag_names separated by ; inside that single column. Something like this..

[AS-IS and TO-BE BS Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THSjA.jpg)

I could use INNER JOIN to combine my three tables (something like below) but tbh Im not sure how to handle multiple queries and manage the foreach. A bit out of my depths.

```
SELECT tag_name
      FROM table_a
          INNER JOIN table_c
                  ON table_c.article_id = table_a.article_id 
          INNER JOIN table_b
                  ON table_c.tag_id = table_b.tag_id
       WHERE table_c.article_id = 'SelectedArticleName'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) function of MySQL (check your MySQL version and related documentation). It enables you to get all data in a single request. It would be something like:

```
SELECT article_id, article_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_name, 
                  ORDER BY tag_name DESC SEPARATOR ';') AS tags
  FROM table_a
      INNER JOIN table_c
              ON table_c.article_id = table_a.article_id 
      INNER JOIN table_b
              ON table_c.tag_id = table_b.tag_id 
      GROUP BY table_a.article_id, table_a.article_name
```

Be aware that the length of the result of GROUP_CONCAT is limited

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet.